# How can I change the title of front-page in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

Maybe, it's very easy, but i don't know how to change the title of front-page in Drupal 8. Could somebody help me?

Comment: you can do it by going to admin of your site then Content -> find the page you want to change title for -> Edit. In the Edit screen you will be able to change Title field

Comment: It is possible if you have created "Basic page" material. In my situation i have overwrite  front-page template and now see only Welcome to My site title...

Comment: ok I understood your question, but want to clarify a bit - do you know about "Promoted to front page" functionality? This basically allows you to set any created page as default front page. You can create Basic page, then you can set it as promoted to front page. Would this be suitable for you or you still need to override base template?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary for me to override template to remove "content" region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change title of the front page view, go to admin/structure/views/view/frontpage, find **Global: Title override** link.

**Note:** This will only change the title of the front page if you're using the default front-page `/node/0` view.

[image]

Open it and it will allow to set custom front page title.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. I've changed my front page to another page besides the default `/node`.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod – Of course this doesn't work then. You changed the front page to display something different than this view.

Comment: @leymannx still learning Drupal, including the concept of a view, so apparently the front-page view is what generates the `/node/0` page. I assume that @RalphRitoch also had this misunderstanding.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod – No prob. Maybe the whole question actually is about the real h1 page title, while RalphRitoch basically answers your question about the title tag in the head.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (Drupal 8.2.1) but I was able to change the title using the administrator interface by installing two plugins. Metatag, and Token which is required by metatag.

https://www.drupal.org/project/token

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag